# Jenkins maven builds fail with 0ms

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We recently migrated jenkins to the LTS version 1.532.2. Ever since, we have been experiencing problems with maven builds failing frequently and claims the entire build took only 0ms as seen in the build trend.

The maven project plugin itself wasn't upgraded as he latest version had a different issue. The current maven project plugin in use is 2.0

Has anyone experienced this behavior?

[image]

Comment: What's in the log of the failing builds? You should be able to get more info there. Also, look in the Jenkins main log...

Comment: Dont see any useful information from the console logs nor from the jenkins master logs.. It just abruptly stops without any useful information

Comment: have you tried restarting the server? single 0 second console output have anything in it?

Comment: Yes did atleast 4-5 times since the upgrade.. No luck..

Comment: Can it be related to the triggering? Too often or conflicting? What's in the 0ms build log?

Comment: Finally the problem turned out to be the refresh frequency in the build pipeline configuration. Setting up the frequency to 20secs or more solved the problem. That was insanely craziest ever debugging..

Comment: Great news! I suggest you post an answer to your own question, where you described what you did to find it and how you fixed it.